# Git->fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

Tags: git

Why does git show this message when I run `git log`, if I've already run

```sh
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Comment: Did you do `git add` or `git add .` ? If you didn't use the `.`, then you didn't actually add anything.

Comment: upsss, I edit the post, the correct is ```git add .```

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `git add` does not add anything. You need to have at least one `pathspec` (path specification) (roughly, it means anything denoting a type of file or directory you want to add). Examples of a pathspec are `.`, `*`, `dir1/` `dir1/one.c` etc. You must've got this error when you did `git add`:

```
hint: Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addEmptyPathspec false"
```

This message says that maybe you want to do a `git add .`. This means that it will add anything it sees as changed.

On running `git commit -m "first commit"` you must've got:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

It also says that it has nothing to commit meaning you never committed anything in the first place.
Finally running a `git log`, you get:

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

which justifies everything which has happened as of now.
I hope this  solves your problem! :)

Best

Comment: the problem is, I think, some wrong with the git configuration and the windows 10 home, because in my other pc work fine (win10 pro), because after I execute ```git add .``` I dont see any message of confirmation, the same happend with ```git commit -m "firts commit"```, just pass some seconds and only the prompt of terminal empty

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't add anything, and possibly didn't even have a change to commit, so no commit was done. Note this would happen if you `git init` an empty directory. If you really want that first commit without any changes, you can do this:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "first commit"
```

Otherwise, once you have a change to make (e.g. a new file), then use:

```
git add .
```

To stage it before committing.